# Array remains unchanged when using sort on it

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort an array of days, I found using a pre-defined array reference is better than the JS Date class method.

My array on which sort is called upon doesn't get sorted, even if I always `return 1` in the callback, the array never changes.

```js
const days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

const toSort = ["monday", "tuesday", "thursday", "friday", "wednesday"];

toSort.sort((a, b) => {
  a = days.indexOf(a);
  b = days.indexOf(b);

  return a < b ? 0 : 1;

  // No matter what I return, the source array remains unchanged
  return a < b ? 1 : 0;
  return 1;
});

console.log(toSort);
```

Something so out of order (haha get it) from using a basic JS function must mean the answer is stupidly obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The snippet sorts the array as expected -> [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas No it does not

Comment: Just to generalize your issue, `sort` expects the callback to return a "tri-state", that is either negative, zero or positive integer. The tri-state reflects the three possible results of the comparison: smaller than (negative), equal (zero) or greater than (positive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
const toSort = ["monday", "tuesday", "thursday", "friday", "wednesday"];    

toSort.sort(function(a, b){  
  return days.indexOf(a) - days.indexOf(b);
});

console.log(toSort);
```

Comment: Shortest answer, I like it

Answer (score 1):

Returning `0` means that the items are equal in terms for order

```js
const days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

const toSort = ["monday", "tuesday", "thursday", "friday", "wednesday"];

toSort.sort((a, b) => {
  a = days.indexOf(a);
  b = days.indexOf(b);

  return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1
});

console.log(toSort);
```

Comment: What's the problem with OPs script? What have you change? Why did you make that change in particular?

Comment: `return (a < b) ? -1 : 1` worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you close it as duplicate?

Comment: @Andreas if you find a duplicate, please do